# Laravel paypal server integration

Tags: laravel, paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal payment in Laravel 5.4 and I've got the following problem:
I've copied this code from their documentation:

```
<div id="paypal-button"></div>

    <script>
        var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL  = '{{ route('pay') }}';
        var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = '{{ route('execute-payment') }}';

        paypal.Button.render({

            env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox'

            commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

            payment: function() {
                 return paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL).then(function(data) {
                       return data.id;
                 });
            },

            onAuthorize: function(data) {
                return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, {
                       paymentID: data.paymentID,
                       payerID:   data.payerID
                }).then(function() {

                // The payment is complete!
               // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
               });
            }

        }, '#paypal-button');
    </script>
```

But when I press the paypal button it gives me internal server error in the console. I guess it's because the csrf token is missing. If that's the case how can I add the token to the reqeust ?

Answer (score 0):

In case your error is cause by a `TokenMismatchException` you would need to add it to the request like so:

```
payment: function() {
    return paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL, {
        _token:    {{csrf_token()}}
    }).then(function(data) {
        return data.id;
    });
},
onAuthorize: function(data) {
    return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, {
        paymentID: data.paymentID,
        payerID:   data.payerID,
        _token:    {{csrf_token()}}
   }).then(function() {
       // The payment is complete!
       // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
   });
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This function is called when the payment is completed
I need to pass the token in the payment function

Answer (score 0):

Laravel comes out of the box with a `csrf-token` [meta tag](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token). So, instead of calling `paypal.request.post` directly, you can do this:

```
<div id="paypal-button"></div>

<script>
  var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL  = '{{ route('pay') }}';
  var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = '{{ route('execute-payment') }}';
  var laravelCsrfToken = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')

  paypal.Button.render({

    env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox'

    commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

    payment: function() {
      return paypal.request({
        method: 'post',
        url: CREATE_PAYMENT_URL,
        headers: {
          'x-csrf-token': laravelCsrfToken
        }
      }).then(function(data) {
        return data.id;
      });
    },

    onAuthorize: function(data) {
      return paypal.request({
        method: 'post',
        url: EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL,
        data: {
          paymentID: data.paymentID,
          payerID:   data.payerID
        },
        headers: {
          'x-csrf-token': laravelCsrfToken
        }
      }).then(function() {
        // The payment is complete!
        // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
      });
    }
  }, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it but I receive this error again

checkout.js:20324 POST http://localhost:8000/pay 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Go to `network` tab in Google Chrome Dev Tools and see what's happening. Or go to Laravel logs to get the error.

Comment: Is the token passed in the header? check in dev tools

Comment: 1. Verify if in your html exists a `csrf-token` meta tag. 2. Do a `console.log(laravelCsrfToken)` in your Javascript.

Comment: I managed to pass the token and dont receive the error anymore
But now paypal says that "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later." I hope it's just temporary problem from them and they fix it soon

Comment: I guess it is temporary, too.